# Laravel new command 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to install a new Laravel app, and I'm getting the following error:

```
  [Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException]  
  Client error response                                 
  [status code] 404                                     
  [reason phrase] Not Found                             
  [url] http://192.241.224.13/laravel-craft.zip
```

I have the latest composer, and used it to install the latest Laravel.

Can anyone help me with this?   I know the error has been corrected in the latest version on GitHub, and I searched for that file on my computer and found it, then confirmed that it already has the new URL that fixed this issue. I have no idea why the old one is still being used.

I even deleted the .Composer file and ran the Composer command again to reinstall Laravel fresh, and it still does the same thing.

Comment: It would help people answer if you could spell out what mean by "install a new Laravel app".  There's many different things this could mean -- if you spell out exactly the steps you're taking it may provide Stack Overflow with the insight we need to figure out why your install process is still looking for the file.

Comment: I was using "laravel new {appname}". You're correct, I should have included that for clarity. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. There was another installation of Laravel that was in the path. I found it, and removed it, then added the correct path.